# Requirement to fetch the latest updated record in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

For the below data, I need to fetch the records with latest revision.
In the below given data I have two rows with Doc# 5 with Item# 048 and Revision 0 and 1 respectively. My requirement is to fetch the all the records with the max revision. @nd example is doc#17 where there are three revisions available 0,1, and 2 but the requirement is to get the latest revision 2.

```
Doc#|   GO#       |    Item#   |Documentationtype  |Revision
1      MNY0005902      064          T-1 DWG            0
2      MNY0005902      59A      Transient Study        0
3      MNY0005902      048      Mimic Panel            0
4      MNY0005902      59A      Transient Study        0
5      MNY0005902      048      Mimic Pane             0
5      MNY0005902      048      Mimic Panel            1
13     MNY0005902      064      T-1 SUB                0
16     MNY0005902      064      T-1 FIO                0
17     MNY0005902      064      T-1 TR                 0
17     MNY0005902      064      T-1 TR                 1
17     MNY0005902      064      T-1 TR                 2
```

Output should be

```
Doc#|   GO#       |    Item#   |Documentationtype  |Revision
1      MNY0005902      064          T-1 DWG            0
2      MNY0005902      59A      Transient Study        0
3      MNY0005902      048      Mimic Panel            0
4      MNY0005902      59A      Transient Study        0
5      MNY0005902      048      Mimic Panel            1
13     MNY0005902      064      T-1 SUB                0
16     MNY0005902      064      T-1 FIO                0
17     MNY0005902      064      T-1 TR                 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this can be easily achieve using `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
    SELECT *, R = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Doc#, Item# ORDER BY Revision DESC)
    FROM   yourtable
) as D
WHERE R = 1
```

Comment: I believe this query gives the oldest revision instead of latest.

Comment: amended. Thanks @RajeshBhat

Answer (score 1):

You can use a Common Table Expression to reduce the data and get only the latest revisions, then select on your table and inner join onto the CTE.

```
;WITH rows AS
(
  SELECT Doc, MAX(Revision) AS Revision
  FROM TheTable
  GROUP BY Doc
)
SELECT TheTable.Doc, TheTable.GO, TheTable.Item, TheTable.DocumentationType, TheTable.Revision
FROM TheTable
INNER JOIN rows ON TheTable.Doc = rows.Doc AND TheTable.Revision = rows.Revision
```

[Working SQLFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/1f721/4), this should also work on MSSQL 2008.

Answer (score 1):

This query should give the expected results.

```
;WITH CTE as(
select *,row_number()over(partition by doc# order by revision desc) RID
from #docs
)

select doc#,Go#,Item#,DocumentationType,Revision from CTE where RID=1
```